# ResXToResource.exe has stopped working

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I'm not sure if this is the place to ask this, but suddenly when trying to build my web application through Visual Studio 2010, I'm getting this error. In my error log I get the following...

"ResGen.exe" exited with code -532459699

I did get a Windows update the night before this happened so I thought this might be the issue. I rolled back the Windows update and I still got the same error. Next, I tried uninstalling VS2010 and then reinstalling it and re-applying SP1. Problem still persists.

I'm hoping someone can help me with this as presently, I cannot build my application. I do have a "slower" backup machine which I can go to but this is definitely not a long-term solution.

Thanks in advance to anyone who can assist or point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

After going in circles for the last day+ I finally stumbled upon this answer which worked for me...

Set the 32-bit flag on resgen.exe

a.     Open a Visual Studio command-prompt as an administrator

b.     Navigate to the Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\bin directory.

c.     ***SAVE A COPY*** of your original resgen.exe file.  This is very important if you want to be able to replace our tweak with the original file without having to repair your installation.
copy resgen.exe regen.exe.old

d.     Set the 32-bit flag to true using corflags.exe
corflags.exe resgen.exe /32BIT+ /Force

e.     Note the warning about strong name issues.  On my machine the build now succeeds, without needing to do any additional work due to strong name issues.  IF you have problems after trying this method, you can try the following to skip string name verification for that assembly-

f.      Register resgen.exe for strong name verification skipping using sn.exe
sn.exe –Vr resgen.exe
 WARNING! This is a security risk.  You are bypassing strongname verification for this assembly, making it possible for malicious code posing as resgen.exe to execute.  To turn verification back on, use sn.exe –Vu resgen.exe

Let me know what you try and whether it is successful or not.

Thanks!

Mike Johnson Software Development Engineer in Test Windows C++ Microsoft Corp.